# Uploading multiple files to FTP via AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, ftp, afnetworking

So i'm new to objective-c and programming at all ), and i'm trying to understand how to download/upload multiple files to FTP. I started with SimpleFTPSample, but everybody says, that using AFNetworking is much simplier, so how i can upload 2 txt files to FTP using AFNetworking. I found only information about sending to http. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is, basically you can't.

AFNetworking is pretty much HTTP(S) only - no support for FTP. It's not apparent from the name, but if you look over here: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking#overview it gets pretty clear.

So you might have to use SimpleFTPSample or check this: https://github.com/nkreipke/FTPManager