# Download folder using AFNetworking in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2

I would like to download a folder which consists several kind of files(png,jpg,mov,txt and pdf). I am using AFNetworking. I have used below code for downloading,

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[Utilities urlencode:imageURL]]];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:str_path append:NO];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
{
    //NSLog(@"Successfully downloaded file to %@", str_path);
}
failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
{
    NSLog(@"Error: %@ =====%@ =======%@", error.localizedDescription,str_path,imageURL);
}];

[operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead)
{
    float progress = totalBytesWritten / (float)totalBytesExpectedToRead;
    NSLog(@"Download Percentage: %f %%", progress*100);
}];

[operation start];
```

The above code works fine for individual files. But i have got error code of 21 while downloading folder. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi,I think you use following library for downloading files form server (https://github.com/oarrabi/Download-Manager) May be it is very useful for you.Thanks

Comment: if you could, put the files into a _.zip_ file and download that file in one session and unzip it on the device; or grab the list of the files in the folder and you can download them one by one.

Comment: yes, but i don't need zip format and getting extract in iphone. So i would prefer to download a folder instead of zip

Answer (score 1):

HTTP does not support downloading multiple files in one request. This is pretty much the same question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14471721/uploading-multiple-files-to-ftp-via-afnetworking) in reverse.

If you have FTP access you can use the [CFFTP API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/CFFTPTasks/CFFTPTasks.html) to download the contents of a directory.